# Is there a more efficient way to implement those 2 function in swi-prolog?

Tags: prolog

Is there a faster way to implement these 2 functions in swi-prolog , in order to save time and memory?

```
insert(Ind,List,Val,NList) :-
    nth0(Ind,List,_,R),
    nth0(Ind,NList,Val,R).

build(X,N,List) :- 
    length(List,N),
    maplist(=(X),List).
```

Explaining: The first one inserts at the Nth position of a list a value and the second one builds a list of N elements all equal to number X

Edit : I have figured out a way to improve insert for my program

```
insert(Ind,List,NList,R,Elem) :-
    Valb=Val,
    Val is Val+1,
    nth0(Ind,NList,Val,R),
    Elem=Valb.
```

This should replace an element of a list with its value plus 1 , but also return the previous Value (Valb) before adding 1 . I know the code is wrong how could I make it right without using nth0 another time?

Comment: Both are *O(n)*. In terms of time complexity no. You can implement the former a bit more efficient by iterating over the two lists concurrently.

Comment: `build(a,N,[b|_])` loops, it could fail in a better implementation

Answer (score 0):

In terms of time complexity, both work in *O(n)* time and *O(n)* memory. You can not construct a list with *n* elements in less than *O(n)* time, and it will require at least *O(n)* memory. One could construct the list lazily and thus postpone the creation, but for a real list, in terms of time complexity.

What we can do however is "merge" the logic of the two predicates, such that we do more per recursive call, for example:

```
build(X,N,List) :-
    var(N),
    !,
    build_gen_(List, X, N).
build(X, N, List) :-
    integer(N),
    !,
    build_num_(N, List, X).

build_gen_([], _, 0).
build_gen_([X|T], X, N) :-
    build_gen_(T, X, N1),
    N is N1 + 1.

build_num_(0, [], _) :-
    !.
build_num_(N, [X|T], X) :-
    N > 0,
    N1 is N-1,
    build_num_(N1, T, X).
```

We thus basically construct a special predicate that performs the two tasks (constructing a list of length `N`, and setting all the elements to `X`) with the same predicate.

I leave specializing the first predicate `insert/4` as an exercise.

Comment: What is `_build2` for a name?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thank you for your answer , please see the edit on my post